# How to call node functions from python and vice versa

Tags: python, node.js, electron

I was previously able to establish communication between javascript and python scripts by using a python library called Eel. However, I began to have issues with Eel when I needed to integrate it with the Electron app. So I am now trying to use sys.stdout in Electron to communicate with python script. Here is my code

Electron App

Main.js

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn
const pythonProcess = spawn('python3', ["./py/test.py"])


pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
   mydata = data.toString()
   console.log('we have data from python ',mydata)
})


function getDataFromPY(data){

   console.log("i've got data")


 }
```

test.py

```
   def testNode():
      print("node has called this python function")


   def helloNode():
       print("hello from python " 


   helloNode()
```

I was able to start the test.py file from the node but I want to be able to call node function from python and vice versa. What is the best method to call specific functions in node from python and vice versa in Electron framework?

Answer (score 0):

There is a helpful library called [Naked][1] (Github page).

```
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js

results = execute_js('AnyScriptFile.js')

if result:
    #success
else:
    #failure
```

There are many other methods out there. But I have tried this and it has worked for me.
[1]: https://github.com/chrissimpkins/naked